# How to access assets from installed package

Tags: python, setup.py

I have a directory structure that looks like this:

```
videocloud
  |
  |---videocloud
  |    |
  |    |---main.py
  |    |---font.ttf
  |
  |---setup.py
```

I need to access `font.ttf` from `main.py`. I can do this by running `main.py` from `videocloud/videocloud/` and accessing `font.ttf` by referencing it. However, the working directory won't always stay the same. After doing `python setup.py install` the package would be installed to `site-packages` and `font.ttf` won't be accessible.

I tried adding this to my setup script:

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    ...
    data_files=[("videocloud", ["NotoSans.ttf"])]
```

but when installing it throws an error:

```
error: can't copy 'NotoSans.ttf': doesn't exist or not a regular file
```

This seems to work though:

```
data_files=[("videocloud", ["videocloud/NotoSans.ttf"])]
```

But even with that, when I tried accessing it by `pkg_resources.resource_filename(__name__, "NotoSans.ttf")` it gives me `KeyError: 'videocloud\\NotoSans.ttf`

Comment: maybe use `Manifest.in` instead of `data_files`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as  Grzegorz Bokota mentions. 
Using a MANIFEST.IN in your package you can include data files/config files which will be installed into site-packages once the package is installed.

check out the documentation on manifest.in
https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/sourcedist.html

I believe you then should be able to import it/at least access it via the site-packages directory structure to get access to it (although the second open feels pretty hacky)